# How to create a vignette with background gradients

Tags: css

[image]

Is there a way to create a background without the use of any actual image files that has a gradient that looks like this?

Not the wood panel texture, but how the left and right are darker and then get lighter as they go inwards.

Comment: I think it is possible if used `gradient` css property. never used it though.

Comment: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/ , http://css3pie.com/demos/gradient-patterns/

Comment: please choose an answer if you found your answer.

Answer (score 37):

#### Box Shadows

You can accomplish this with `box-shadow` or `radial-gradient`. Let's look at the first option:

```css
.box {
    width: 300px; height: 300px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5em 1em #000;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/300");
}
```

This uses an `inset` shadow which overlays the elements background image. The effect resembles your example photo:

[image]

#### Radial Gradients

You can do this pretty easily using several linear gradients, or a radial gradient:

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    background:
        radial-gradient(transparent, black),
        url("http://lorempixel.com/500/500");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/t8N5M/

If your browser supports [gradients](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradients), [cover](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts), and [multiple backgrounds](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds), you'll see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this online editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to generate gradients of different orientation like `radial`, `horizontal` etc. you can also control the opacity of your gradient.

here is JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/banded_krait/AZK5d/2/

Answer (score 0):

as a web designer, i love the result of [interstellarDust's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22216780/7607344) code.

**Reasons:**

1. The stop points of gradients are customizable. so the radial gradients
   would give me a nice & round vignette not like the square shape gradient from box shadow inset's effect.
2. The 0% opacity of center area help my audiences easy to focus at the center of image. *(but if you plan to put an overlay bright color text, thicker opacity vignette background will make the text more readable.)*

i've messed with gradients stop points and opacity of interstellarDust's code here:

```css
#img_container{
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
#img_container img{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:4;
}
.gradient{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    /* http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+100&0+50,0.5+100 */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Vignette with background gradients</title>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Original by <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/22216780">banded_krait</a></p>

  <div id="img_container">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" alt="" />
      <div class="gradient"></div>
  </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```