# Black gradient layer over an IMG without using linear-gradient?

Tags: html, css

I have an `img` tag and I want to add another gradient div layer on top of it ( that gradient div will have text).

Something like this :

[image]

I already know that I [can do this with `linear-gradient`](http://peter.coffee/how-to-use-css-pseudo-elements-to-add-a-gradient-to-images) but I don't want that becuase not all mobile versions supports this feature.

Also - I've already seen that it can be achieved [via `box-shadow` with `inset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22216713/859154)

[image]

But it's not the same. I *only* want top and bottom gradient  - without any differences on the edges. ( just like in my first picture here ^)

[*This is what i've tried :  JSBIN*](http://jsbin.com/luxojaruno/edit?html,css,output)

[image]

But again , I don't want the edges to be darker. I want only the strip in the red rectangle to be from left to right.And also - symmetric -  in the bottom ( same gradient should be at the bottom).

**Question**

How can I fix my code to achieve straight-equal gradients in top and bottom without using `linear-gradient` ?

NB

> I need to add text on that gradient div ( text is from DB) . So It can not be a pseudo ::before/::after element div.

Comment: You can create separate `box-shadow` using `pseudo` elements as `:after` and `:before` of your img container tag.

Comment: So you just want the gradient at the top and bottom, from the left edge to the right?

Comment: you can use Photoshop or any other image editing tool to do that

Comment: @AndreiV Right. Just like in my first image in the post. ( and it has to be a layer becuase i'm going to add a text in that gradient)

Comment: Gradients have great support on mobile browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=gradients

Comment: @Muhammad I'm trying to do it via CSS.

Comment: @Turnip Well , maybe but [linear gradient is not supported  in some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) , look here. https://i.imgur.com/dLkBZF1.jpg . anyway I don't want to use linear gradient

Comment: `:before` and `:after` box-shadows are your best option then...

Comment: @AndreiV I need to add text on it. I can't add text on a psuedo element (which is the result of before/after::)

Comment: You want too many things :) Use two separate `div`s or `span`s then and set the box shadow as tall as the elements. Absolutely positioned. </random>

Comment: @AndreiV adding a div with gradient on top of an image ?  That's not too much :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using multiple shadows you can target the sides you want.

Here done setting the *spread radius* (4:th parameter) of the blur to a negative value, keeping it from spreading along the sides, and use the *horizontal* and *vertical* offset of the shadow to, in this case, target only the top and bottom.

```css
.innerDiv
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background :transparent;
  opacity:1;
  border:solid 1px red;
  padding:5px;
  z-index:92299; 
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 50px 50px -40px rgba(0,0,0,1),
    inset 0 -50px 50px -40px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div style='position:relative;border:solid 1px lightgray;height:400px'>
  <div class='innerDiv'>
    Some text
  </div>
  <img src='http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/BMW-2-series.jpg' height="400px" />
</div>
```

---

Based on earlier comments, here is a pseudo element version producing the exact same result, and by using the `CSS attr()` avoiding the issue of *compile time data* in the CSS.

I also added a script to show the text can be added dynamically as well.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var div = document.querySelector('div');
  var text = div.getAttribute('data-text');
  div.setAttribute('data-text', text + ', and this were added dynamically using script');
})
```

```css
div
{
  position:relative;
}
div::after
{
  content: attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background :transparent;
  opacity:1;
  border:solid 1px red;
  padding:5px;
  z-index:92299; 
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 50px 50px -40px rgba(0,0,0,1),
    inset 0 -50px 50px -40px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div style='position:relative;border:solid 1px lightgray;height:400px' data-text="Some text set using an attribute in the markup">
  <img src='http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/BMW-2-series.jpg' height="400px" />
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. No other words ( second solution idea is using JS and I think that attaching event handler to an element just to add text when data attribute is changed - is a bit awkward and slow down things. :-) but the first code is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Thanks ... and note that the second solution has 2 parts, one that does not use JS (remove the JS and you'll see text is still there)

Comment: @lsgon BTW after a second look  -  I see that the shadow pollute the right and left margins http://jsbin.com/payikihoca/3/edit?html,css,output . this is not like I wanted... Se here https://i.imgur.com/zp0jUMy.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir One need to play with the values to get it in place: http://jsbin.com/pezekazuwi/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2):

As I also suggested in comment that if you can achieve this using `pseudo` elements as `::after` and `::before` of your `img` container *DOM* element.

You can define the `pseudo` elements and then play with the `box-shadow` to replicating that gradient effect.

Here I have made some changes in your *DOM* structure as:

### Code Snippet:

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img-container::after,
.img-container::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.img-container::before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 25px 16px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 25px 16px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}

.img-container::after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -25px 16px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px -25px 16px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src='http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/BMW-2-series.jpg' height="400px" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank but I wrote in the comments that it has to be a layer because I should add text to it. I can't add text to a psuedo div element. I will also write this in question

Comment: @RoyiNamir I think that is not possible in css without involving extra elements, and as you said you want to add content so you can add content when you have a container element while image cannot hold contents.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Actually you can. You can add text from (data)attributes set on the main element. Here's an [example](https://davidwalsh.name/css-content-attr).

Comment: @AndreiV yeah but that's a compile time data. My data comes from a DB. Just as any normal layer will have a specific data to that image

Comment: @RoyiNamir then create two separate *DOM* element and put your text there and position them accordingly on shadowed `pseudo` elements all you have to do is to increase the shadow radius.

Comment: Regardless from where and when it comes. If you can write it in the attribute of the main element, it will be used by the pseudo elements.

Comment: @AndreiV Oh it will require JS to get in action. this will make things slower and that element will have to wait for JS to "fix things up".

Answer (score 1):

(using the answer of `@vivekkupadhyay` as example) you could just make an overlay div and give this the inset shadow. Then you can add whatever content you want.

```css
.img-container,
.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left 0;
}

.img-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  }

.img-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img-overlay {
  width: 120%;
  height: 100%;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 25px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 25px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  margin-left: -25px;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src='http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/BMW-2-series.jpg' height="400px" />
  <div class="img-overlay">
    some text
   </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** you could also make two seperate overlay div's for top and bottom if you want the to both have content, but this is just a quick example.

Comment: Cool Just like I wanted. [I did  this like in your code](http://jsbin.com/vovacivaba/1/edit?html,css,output) But I'm really trying to get the colors [gradient as in this picture](https://i.imgur.com/62czQMx.jpg). I there something I'm missing here ?

Comment: I dont know the exact values of the example you gave but try playing with this: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow (where horizontal, vertical are 0 and inset is active). Here you can tweak the values untill you got the desired result.